# request.getInputStream() returns null in JBoss

Tags: servlets, request, jboss6.x

`Request.getInputStream()` returns `null` in JBoss

```
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(request.getInputStream()));
```

Answer (score 0):

That would indicate that the request has no body. [javax.servlet.ServletRequest.getInputStream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getInputStream--) is only for reading the body of the request.

I also assume that you're not handing the request object off to another thread for processing - that will definitely cause you problems.

Note also that [javax.servlet.ServletRequest.getReader()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getReader--) can be used instead of your code fragment.

Comment: Its has body because it's working on Weblogic and tomcat

Comment: Which JBoss 6 is it? JBoss AS 6 or JBoss EAP 6? (They're entirely different)

Comment: Thanks for your replyJBoss 6

Comment: It is JBoss AS 6

Comment: JBoss AS 6 uses Tomcat for it's servlet container. Perhaps you could use something like tcpdump/wireshark to verify the incoming request structure

Comment: Can you please share some part of code how to use ' tcpdump/wireshark '  in my servlet.   Some part of my code inside do post as..............................        .BufferedReader in = null; in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(request.getInputStream()));

Comment: I am getting data for Request.getHeaderNames(); and all other methods expect request.getInputstream and request.getReader and request.SQLstring() can you please help me on this

Comment: Hi Steve C,Now I deployed on JBoss 6.4 EAP getting same problem  can you please help me on it Thanks in Advance

Comment: What is `request.SQLstring()`?

Comment: How is this request composed and delivered to your code?